# What does this javascript syntax / pattern mean?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I've seen this pattern in a code and I'm trying to understand what's the idea behind it

```
foo : {
    //some code here
    console.log('1');
}
```

foo is some html node, and console.log represents some code. I see that console.log always executes and I see no reason to use this pattern and not just writing console.log directly.

also you can see that it works if I use it on an undefined variable.

```
this_does_not_exists : {
    console.log(2);
}
```

what can be the reason for someone to use this pattern?

Answer (score 3):

That is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and has nothing to do with variables. These are generally useful only when dealing with `while` or `for` loops when you want to `break` or `continue` from one other than the inner-most one.

Example from MDN:

```
loop1:
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      //The first for statement is labeled "loop1"
   loop2:
   for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {   //The second for statement is labeled "loop2"
      if (i == 1 && j == 1) {
         continue loop1;
      }
      console.log("i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
   }
}
```

In this example, the code is `continue`ing the outer loop from within the inner loop.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about the label

Comment: @RomanKrom, i dont blame you. this is 2014, no one uses label and goto-like syntaxes.